# Can I change the network of an existing Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have a couple of Google Compute Engine (GCE) virtual machines spread across two GCE networks. Now I want to move them all to one shared network but I can't find a way to change the network of an existing VM. Is there a way to do this or do I have to recreate the VMs in the new network?

Comment: Do you wish to change the zone of the VM or its external IP? You can change the external IP but not the zone (=internal network)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488549/moving-google-compute-vm-instances-between-networks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this and it's quite simple.

Use the Instance-DeleteAccessConfig and Instace-AddAccessConfig methods to hot-remove & hot-add network configurations on running instances.

In this case, you'll first call deleteAccessConfig on the instance to remove it from the first network, then call addAccessConfig to add it to the second.

Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/deleteAccessConfig https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/addAccessConfig

Comment: Chris, It's unclear how to do this as the addAccessConfig endpoint doesn't appear to accept a network name or id... so I'm unsure how that would allow you to change the network. Could you please clarify that you aren't providing instructions on how to change the IP address?

Comment: I don't understand how to do what this answer suggests...  but just deleting and recreating my instance (making sure not to delete its disk) worked fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

You have to recreate the VM's in the new network.

Comment: Brian, I am inclined to agree with your answer, but do you have any official documentation you can point to that backs this up? Thanks, Jeff

Comment: I can't find any documentation explicitly saying this, but when you create an instance and choose a network for its interface, there's help text saying _Network interface is permanent_.

Answer (score 8):

Google has recently added this feature and you are now able to edit the network.

Simply select the VM you want to change the network for and hit the 'Edit' button at the top. Then scroll down to 'Network Interfaces' and you will see a pencil next to the nic.

[image: network interface]

Comment: This option indeed exists! However, it seems to work only if the source and target locations are the same :)

Answer (score 5):

### Google Developers Console

Although you cannot directly move an instance, the Google Developers Console now has the function to **Clone this instance**. Go to [Google Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console/), navigate to **Project ID -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances ->** . Scroll down to the end and you should see the option

[image: Google Cloud Console]

After clicking on **Clone this instance**, you will be brought to the new instance creation page, with an option to select which Zone you wish to clone the target instance.

[image: Create new instance]

---

### gcutil

You can use the `gcutil moveinstances` command to move an instance from a zone to another zone. You can even move a list of instances using regular expression, for example:

```
gcutil moveinstances --source_zone=zone-a
                             --destination_zone=zone-b "i-[0-9]" "b-.*"
```

For more information, type `gcutil help moveinstances`

Comment: The question was how to move instances between networks, not between zones. This is a great explanation, but doesn't cover the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a snapshot of the vm instance, then create a new vm instance from that snapshot and specify a different network.