# Moving Google Compute VM instances between Networks

Tags: google-compute-engine

Does anyone know how to move an existing VM instance between Google Cloud Networks configured on a project? I know you can specify the Network at the point of creating an new VM, but there doesn't appear to be a facility for changing it once instantiated.
    Any pointers appreciated!
    -Paul

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to move an existing GCE VM instance to a different network, you will first need to delete the VM instance while keeping all its disks (`--keep-disks all`  flag with gcloud command) [1]. Then create a new VM instance with the existing boot disk [2],[3] and attach other disks to the new VM instance if there is any.

All of the above mentioned steps can be done using the Developers Console as well.

[Link 1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete): `gcloud compute instances delete NAME --keep-disks all`
[Link 2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#usingrootpd): Using an existing root persistent disk 
[Link 3](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create): `gcloud compute instances create`

Comment: @user3446361 In that case, could you upvote/accept his answer, to let next users who come on your question know it's the correct one? (you should have a checkmark next to the score of the answer, and you should be able to click on it)

Comment: Can confirm. As of today, 2019-11-22, this is still the only way. An existing instance cannot have a new nic added (or any nics deleted), and nicN network cannot be changed. However flexible the GCE is, it still lacks the good old "unplug this Ethernet cable and plug into a different router" thing, which is so natural with physical machines.